# How to filter Even and Odd numbers and move/copy them to an empty column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a simple problem. i have a column with numbers. i need to filter them to even and odd numbers, but if a number is even than i need to copy or move it to "even-number-column" in the same table. if the number is odd then  move it to "odd-number-column" in the same table.

this is my code:

```
select distinct all_numbers, even-number-column,  odd-number-column
 case when all_numbers%2=0 
    then UPDATE my_table  SET even-number-column = all_numbers
    else UPDATE my_table  SET odd-number-column = all_numbers
    end
 from my_table ;
```

Comment: It's unclear to me if you just want to *select* the values or if you want to (permanently) **change** (=update) the values in the table.

Comment: i want permanently change it . so that i will have three columns. 1.all_numbers, 2. even, 3. odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a `SELECT`:

```
select 
     distinct all_numbers,
     CASE 
        WHEN when all_numbers%2 = 0  THEN all_numbers 
        ELSE 0 -- or NULL
     END as even-number-column,  
     CASE 
        WHEN when all_numbers%2 = 1  THEN all_numbers 
        ELSE 0 -- or NULL
     END as odd-number-column 
 from my_table ;`
```

If you want an update

```
UPDATE my_table  
SET 
    even-number-column = CASE 
                             WHEN when all_numbers%2 = 0  THEN all_numbers 
                             ELSE even-number-column -- or change for 0 or NULL
                         END,
    odd-number-column  = CASE 
                             WHEN when all_numbers%2 = 1  THEN all_numbers 
                             ELSE odd-number-column  -- or change for 0 or NULL
                         END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to make it simple

```
update t
set 
  odd  = (array[null, all_numbers])[all_numbers % 2 + 1],
  even = (array[all_numbers, null])[all_numbers % 2 + 1]
```

Comment: @Juan Thank you for the edit. That is what happens when I try to do 2 tasks at once.

Comment: no problem, Im still checking are postgres arrays base `0` or `1` ?

Comment: @Juan The default is base 1. There is a decorator to change that.